# Many comments under my answer

Tags: discussion, comments

My answer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296913/is-it-incorrect-to-say-im-20-years-old-next-month/296918#296918) has garnered a gratifying number of up votes, as well as some down votes, and a very long tail of comments, in which people either agree with me enthusiastically (British speakers) or say I'm completely wrong (American speakers). I did think of deleting the damned thing, but (a) it's been accepted (b) that would be chickening out. Is it likely that the mods think the comments deserve to stay, or is it just that they haven't noticed them? I tried clicking the 'move to chat' pop-up, but it said 'move to chat failed'.

Comment: Flag one comment and ask the mods to migrate the lorry load to chat. Users do not have these supernatural powers. Overall the comments are engaging and interesting but if they do stress you out you can ask the moderators to delete them.

Comment: Comment chains under two answers to that question have been moved to chat. The ELL moderation team is unprecedentedly shorthanded, and I just had a very hectic day. Next time try flagging your own post.

Comment: Yes. I'm on vacation with limited access. Fortunately, there's an [election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5) coming up.

Comment: Most of the comments were deleted, but more than half of those deleted were your own comments. (In the future, you might want to simply resist the urge to reply to everyone who comments under your post.)

Comment: I really don't like this sort of deletion. You didn't update your answer to cover the information given in the comments, i.e. that you were speaking from an informal British English perspective. And the thing about chats is that they go away after a while. So now future users will see this accepted, highly voted answer and lack that additional context.  Informative comments should only be removed if the information is incorporated into the Answer or is in another comment, IMHO. Mods get way too "move to chat" happy, forgetting that this makes them go away permanently over time.

Comment: @trlkly I'm.not aware that chat messages disappear or fade away in time. On the contrary, it's impossible for a user to delete a comment once it's been shifted to a chat room.

Comment: @Glorfindelglo hi, can you tell me what happened to user60033's second meta post. It didn't have any answers but it generated a lot if good comments. Was it deleted by the system or by the team or...? Thanks.

Comment: I find he chat system unusable due to font adf interface issues. As a result I will not read or respond to comments in chat, and if I think a comment of mine was informative and important, i will re-post it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've encountered previous Answers where I would click to follow the link to the appropriate chat, and would be told the room no longer existed. it seems that chat rooms disappear after a certain period of time has passed. What that time period is, I do not know.

Comment: @trlkly could well be, that has not happened to me but then I don't always click on the link going to chat. I think, but Glorfindel can confirm, that chat rooms are frozen after a period of activity and depending on the number of comments, are preserved. I think preserving three or four comments for "eternity" makes little sense but then one has to ask why bother migrating when there are so few comments in the first place?